# Rails generating development_structure.sql - order of dump

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, oracle11g

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 and have

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

in my config/application.rb.

In an Oracle 11g database, I've defined a table with virtual columns that depend on user-defined functions:

```
CREATE TABLE BAR (
  ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
  STATUS NUMBER(19, 0) DEFAULT 1,
  CALCULATED_STATUS NUMBER(19,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (MY_FUNCTION(STATUS)) VIRTUAL)
```

When Rake performs a db:test:clone_structure (Tasks: TOP => default => spec => db:test:clone_structure), I'm hitting:

OCIError: ORA-00904: "FOO"."MY_FUNCTION": invalid identifier: CREATE TABLE "BAR" (...

I think what is happening is that db:structure:dump exports the tables before the functions so in development_structure.sql, the CREATE FUNCTION MY_FUNCTION appears after the CREATE TABLE BAR statement.

Do I have to go in and monkeypatch how db:structure:dump works?

Thanks.

Comment: I've found that the Rails schema dumper is exceptionally naive and is easily confused by anything that's not a table. I've had to make extensive patches to it to handle triggers, views, and full-text indexes without completely exploding. I hope you can find a standard solution to this, though.

Comment: Where do you typically make your patches? I've been seeking ways around this problem, but I keep finding myself reaching the same conclusion.

Comment: First step is to create a `config/initializer` file that can do the job. If it works and you want to formalize it, convert that into a fully-fledged gem.

Comment: I ended up locating the applicable source code in https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced and overrode structure_dump and structure_dump_db_stored_code methods in a file I plonked into config/initializers.

Comment: If you have an answer to this, you might want to post it and accept it for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up locating the applicable source code in github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced and overrode structure_dump and structure_dump_db_stored_code methods in a file I plonked into config/initializers.